# Steam (via Wine) crashes after login - any troubleshooting tips?

Tags: wine, steam

The Steam client crashes after I login. After submitting my credentials, Steam displays a dialog box informing me the client is 'connecting'.  I then see the Steam main page and news page displayed for roughly a second or so before the client crashes.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 (I think..what's the best way to verify? uname only displays Linux) which I've installed on a usb flash drive using a capser-rw file for persistence.

wine-1.3.14

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.  How do I identify if the problem is with wine or steam or the video card driver, or what?  Any ideas?

Hardware:

- motherboard: ECS Elitegroup 945GCT-M
- sound: integrated audio
- video: ATI Radeon X1950

console output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Steam$ wine Steam.exe 
fixme:process:GetLogicalProcessorInformation ((nil),0x32e488): stub
fixme:process:GetLogicalProcessorInformation (0x1010c00,0x32e488): stub
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000100, 00000000): partial stub.
fixme:urlmon:CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled 5, 0x00000002, 1, stub
fixme:urlmon:CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled 10, 0x00000002, 1, stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x1009a, 2, 0x32d334, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x1009a, 3, 0x32d338, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x1009a, 4, 0x32d33c, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x100a2, 2, 0x32d964, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x100a2, 3, 0x32d968, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x100a2, 4, 0x32d96c, 4) stub
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {77f10cf0-3db5-4966-b520-b7c54fd35ed6} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {77f10cf0-3db5-4966-b520-b7c54fd35ed6} could be created for context 0x1
fixme:wbemprox:wbem_locator_ConnectServer 0x1ab5f0, L"ROOT\\CIMV2", (null), (null), (null), 0x00000080, (null), (nil), 0x42bbee8)
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x100ae, 2, 0x32d8cc, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x100ae, 3, 0x32d8d0, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x100ae, 4, 0x32d8d4, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x100b6, 2, 0x32d80c, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x100b6, 3, 0x32d810, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x100b6, 4, 0x32d814, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x100c0, 2, 0x32d2e4, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x100c0, 3, 0x32d2e8, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x100c0, 4, 0x32d2ec, 4) stub
fixme:winhttp:WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser returning no proxy used
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x100dc, 2, 0x32d94c, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x100dc, 3, 0x32d950, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x100dc, 4, 0x32d954, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x10118, 2, 0x32da8c, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x10118, 3, 0x32da90, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x10118, 4, 0x32da94, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x10122, 2, 0x32d514, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x10122, 3, 0x32d518, 4) stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x10122, 4, 0x32d51c, 4) stub
fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
```

Comment: This would actually go in the winehg bug section. Anyway if you can, please provide, video card, sound card, motherboard, etc..

Comment: @CYREX Hardware added above. Sorry about asking this in the wrong spot.  Do you mean I should have posted on http://www.winehq.org instead of here?

Comment: Correct since they have a database to track down bugs like this.

Comment: `cat /etc/lsb-release` will tell you your Ubuntu version.

Comment: Also `lsb_release -a` will work. Note that what Oli suggests and what i suggest are the same thing. typing `lsb_release -a` will look for the info as Oli mention above.

Answer (score 1):

Not that this is a guarantee, but but you could try installing steam using [Playonlinux](http://packages.ubuntu.com/Playonlinux) [image: Install Playonlinux]. I have Steam installed using this tool and I don't have any problems with it so far (except for it being heavy on resources).

Since Playonlinux takes care of all the major setup for you, it should *just work*, and if it doesn't, then you know the problem lies in your hardware or your Ubuntu install.

**UPDATE**
Since you see you do not have 3D acceleration in your comments, I'm going to guess that you do not have proprietary drivers installed? If you don't this can lead to some of the problems you are facing. You would want to install these (if possible) for your graphics card, and then try and see if steam works again.

Comment: yep, playonlinux is good option that chooses prom profile what program runs better with what wine version and with what configuration.

Comment: I installed Playonlinux followed by installing Steam via Playonlinux.  The install seemed to go fine except it threw a warning `You don't seem to have 3D acceleration`.  At this point I'm only trying to get the steam client to run, so I'm not worried about acceleration, but perhaps it shows my issue is video driver/hardware related.  Unfortunately, launching steam with POL results in nearly the same behavior.  I get prompted for credentials, it shows a 'connecting' message, then crashes.  Console result is very simiar: `fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but this sounds like the problem I had with the steam browser. I added `-silent` to the end of my command line and I can start steam fine now using wine. It's only when the steam browser pops up after quitting a game that it ultimately crashes. At least I'm able to play my games, though. Buying games and using the friend services that would normally require a browser are best done through a regular browser like Firefox.